# Magento 2.3 - Intergration varnish cache with, error socket :80: address already use

Tags: magento2.3, configuration, nginx, varnish

When I check status Varnish, always receive error :

> Error: Could not reopen listen socket :80: Address already in use.

But, run command `sudo netstat -nlpt`, don't have process using port :80 ???

What did I do something wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Please change port and check it.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Change port ? 
I read guide from devdocs, varnish always uses port :80 !
Can i use any port, eg: 5000 ?

Comment: yes. you can set any port.

Comment: (y) Ok @DhadukMitesh, let's me try

Comment: Is that worked after changed to 5000? I also tried 5000, but there is no luck

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a misconfiguration.

##### Systemd

Check `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/varnish.service`

`-a` (listener address) needs to be set to `:80`

However, `-T` is the CLI listener should be set to `localhost:6082`. This was the one I misconfigured this as `:80`, causing varnish to want to open 2 listeners on port 80.

##### /etc/defaults

There's also daemonopts in `/etc/defaults/varnish` that may have been misconfigured. The same `-a` and `-T` options are in there.